# How to run MSDN code example "How to: Create Pre-Computed Tasks"?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library, async-await, async-ctp

Trying to run C# code example ["How to: Create Pre-Computed Tasks" (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228607.aspx) in .NET 4.0 Async CTP, having made changes:

- `Task.FromResult` ---> `TaskEx.FromResult`
- `Task.FromResult` ---> `TaskEx.FromResult`
- `Task.Run(async () =>`  ---> `TaskEx.RunEx(async () =>`
  (also tried `TaskEx.Run(async () =>`)

butt getting the compilation error:

> Since '`System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>`' is async and returns
>   Task, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression

How to change the code in order to run this example?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

// Demonstrates how to use Task<TResult>.FromResult to create a task  
// that holds a pre-computed result. 
class CachedDownloads
{
  // Holds the results of download operations. 
  static ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> cachedDownloads =
     new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();

  // Asynchronously downloads the requested resource as a string. 
  public static Task<string> DownloadStringAsync(string address)
  {
    // First try to retrieve the content from cache. 
    string content;
    if (cachedDownloads.TryGetValue(address, out content))
    {

      return TaskEx //****** Task.FromResult ---> TaskEx.FromResult   
             .FromResult<string>(content);
    }

    // If the result was not in the cache, download the  
    // string and add it to the cache. 
    return TaskEx.RunEx //****** Task.Run  --> TaskEx.RunEx (TaskEx.Run)
      (async () =>    
    {
      content = await new WebClient().DownloadStringTaskAsync(address);
      cachedDownloads.TryAdd(address, content);
      return content;//*****Error
    });
  }

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    // The URLs to download. 
    string[] urls = new string[]
      {
         "http://msdn.microsoft.com",
         "http://www.contoso.com",
         "http://www.microsoft.com"
      };

    // Used to time download operations.
    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

    // Compute the time required to download the URLs.
    stopwatch.Start();
    var downloads = from url in urls
                    select DownloadStringAsync(url);
    TaskEx.WhenAll(downloads)//*** Task.WhenAll -->  TaskEx.WhenAll
          .ContinueWith(results =>
    {
      stopwatch.Stop();

      // Print the number of characters download and the elapsed time.
      Console.WriteLine
            ("Retrieved {0} characters. Elapsed time was {1} ms."
              , results.Result.Sum(result => result.Length)
              , stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    })
    .Wait();

    // Perform the same operation a second time. The time required 
    // should be shorter because the results are held in the cache.
    stopwatch.Restart();
    downloads = from url in urls
                select DownloadStringAsync(url);

    TaskEx.WhenAll(downloads)//*** Task.WhenAll -->  TaskEx.WhenAll
          .ContinueWith(results =>
    {
      stopwatch.Stop();

      // Print the number of characters download and the elapsed time.
      Console.WriteLine("Retrieved {0} characters. Elapsed time was {1} ms.",
         results.Result.Sum(result => result.Length),
         stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    })
    .Wait();
  }
}
```

**Update:**

Does this code example without my updates for Async CTP run in .NET 4.5?

Comment: Why are you using the CTP now that the RTM version is available? This could easily be a bug in the CTP that was fixed.

Comment: Because RTM is not installable in Windows XP and .NET 4.0 on machine with .NET 4.5 is different from .NET 4.0 on machine without 4.5 installed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C# compiler was enhanced in VS2012 to be smarter about generic overload resolution in the presence of `async` lambdas (i.e., `Func<Task>` and family). Since you're on VS2010, you'll have to help it out here and there.

The clue is in the type of your `async` lambda as displayed in your error message: `System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>`.

What it *should* be is `System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.String>>`.

So I would try this:

```
return TaskEx.RunEx<string> //****** Task.Run  --> TaskEx.RunEx (TaskEx.Run)
  (async () =>    
{
  content = await new WebClient().DownloadStringTaskAsync(address);
  cachedDownloads.TryAdd(address, content);
  return content;//*****Error
});
```